# how to save which button was selected in alertdialog box so that it never shows again?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog, rating-system

I need some help with this, as I was searching for an answer all results were unhelpful I just want straight forward code to copy and paste so that I can save what was selected and never show the dialog box again.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            AlertDialog.Builder b=  new  AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Review and Rate Converjz!")
                    .setMessage("Have you enjoyed Converjz? If you wouldn't mind to take a minute of your time and rate/review this app," +
                            "that would be much appreciated!")
                    .setPositiveButton("RATE/REVIEW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TechnologyForTomorrow.Converjz");
                                    Intent openPlayStore = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                                    try {
                                        startActivity(openPlayStore);
                                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                                    }
                                dialog.dismiss();


                                }


                            }

                    )
                    .setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();

                                }
                            }
                    );
            b.show();


        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use code below to store the key that user has chosen in application preferences.

```
private static final String settingsKey = "MyAppSettings";
private static final String hasUserRatedAppKey= "hasUserRatedApp";
public static boolean hasUserRatedApp(Context act)
{
    SharedPreferences pref = act.getSharedPreferences(settingsKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return pref.getBoolean(hasUserRatedAppKey, false);
}

public static void setHasUserRated(Context context, boolean rated)
{
    SharedPreferences pref = act.getSharedPreferences(settingsKey, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = pref.edit();
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean(hasUserRatedAppKey, rated);
    preferencesEditor.commit();
}
```

and set the value of rated in setPositiveButton:

```
.setPositiveButton("RATE/REVIEW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                ....
                            setHasUserRated(getContext(),true);
                            dialog.dismiss();


                            }


                        }

                )
                ....
```

**Edit:** I missed a part:

before showing the alert dialog, you must check to see if app has been rated before, thats why I included hasUserRatedApp function :

```
if(!hasUserRatedApp(MyActivityClass.this))
{
    AlertDialog.Builder b= ...
}
```

Comment: it can't resolve the getContext() method and I changed act in the setHasUserRated() method to context

Comment: Just used the alertdialog b.getContext instead and had to change it to final after that it says b may have not been initialized. Please help

Comment: are you using it in your activity class or fragment?

Comment: just use MyActivityClass.this instead of getContext() if you are using this in activity. replace MyActivityClass with your activity name.

Comment: I did tested it on my phone, the dialog shows up again after restarting the activity or the app as a whole. Still now working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101138/discussion-between-noah-tanenholtz-and-sina-rezaei).

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for your question, ***straight forward**

https://github.com/danialgoodwin/android--one-time-alert-dialog